# How do I use ASP.NET Identity across my MVC and WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-identity-2

As a warning, I am very new to ASP.NET Identity. I have a project I am working on, and am trying to create different projects to better organize it. I have my UI layer, which is an MVC5 project, and my WebAPI, which is the API that will get called to perform various actions.

I want to use ASP.NET Identity 2.0 to authenticate and authorize actions in both projects.  What is the proper way to do this?

I have two projects in the same solution. Let's say that I run debugging for both of the projects, I want to test being able to authenticate in the UI, then try and access a protected API call and see if it works.

However, if the Identity information is configured in the UI (using the default template), how do I make sure the API properly authenticates users?

Comment: You can use Fiddler to create a GET request that points to your authentication method and passes in the username/password. Look into: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to perform all user actions via the Web API, including authentication and authorization, as well as other Identity-related tasks such as registering and confirming new user accounts. This way, your presentation layer (whether it is a web, desktop or mobile application) will be responsible only for interacting with your API and presenting the data (as it supposed to be).

Check out [this series](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) of blog posts that demonstrate how to implement this approach using ASP.NET Web API and AngularJS.

Comment: the series you reference targets AngularJS.  Do you know if there are any posts out there that describe doing something similar with MVC?